# Python beautifulsoup, scraping a table in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I recently started to get interested in Web scraping via the python library beautifulsoup4, My goal is to get The data about the covid-19 cases (in Morocco is a good start); The website my info is in is : "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
There is a Big Table with all the info, i've tried to do something like this :

```
U = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
response = requests.get(U)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
info = html_soup.find_all('tr', class_='even')
print(info)
```

But the info list is empty i tried to change classes and the Tags but it seems like i'm doing something wrong (The morrocco info is on the 30 row)

***UPDATE***: i used selenium to get my info, btw i use google collab so it was kinda hard but now way better
[Da link for the solution in a python notebook format](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hd8qrB4mRgnO8cTD3CqV0oEKOWooGahP?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is being dynamically generated via JS.  If you go into your browser and disable Javascript in the dev tools, you will see that there are no elements with `<tr class="even">`

You will either need to find out where the data is being obtained (via some web API) using a tool like [HTTP Trace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-trace/idladlllljmbcnfninpljlkaoklggknp?hl=en-US) or use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which will run the Javascript to load the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a dictionary for tag attributes:

```
info = html_soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'even'})
```

Answer (score 0):

This gave me a full list countries.

```
url       = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'

response  = requests.get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
info      = html_soup.find_all('a', {'class':'mt_a'})


print(info[29].text) # returns Marocco


# All the rest

for i in info:  
  print(i.text)
```

Comment: Not really, i want the Data and as said in the upper it's js generated i need to either use selenium or HTTP trace i'm going to look into it